# Comparing Neural Network to ARMA

Tags: neural-networks, arima, aic, model-comparison, mse

I used a neural network tool in MATLAB to predict data, and it gave it's accuracy as MSE and an R-value. 
I used the econometricModeler tool in MATLAB to predict data using ARMA. It gave it's accuracy like this:

[image]

How can I convert one of these measures to the other to see which method is more accurate?

Comment: What do you think about my answer? Does it answer your question? If so, you may accept it by clicking on the tick mark to the left. Otherwise, you may ask for further clarification. This is [how Cross Validated works](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in using the models for prediction, do not compare their performance based on in-sample measures of fit. (In principle you could do that with the help of AIC, but you do not have the AIC value for the neural network.) Use cross validation (or in a time series setting, rolling windows) to do that in a pseudo out-of-sample fashion.